# Application insight .NET | Custom metrics don't show up in portal.azure.com under metrics

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I have application insight running with a "pay as you go" model.
Standard performance metrics show up in the portal.
Custom metrics don't show up in the metrics section.

My Environment.
A custom .NET core console app running plain TCP sockets. (no ASP.NET CORE)
using

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.7.2" />
```

The Telemetry class is constructed with the default constructor ( and no XML config file)

The custom metrics are created like

```
Telemetry.Client.GetMetric("number of clients").TrackValue(600.0);
```

Question:
What do i miss or doing wrong, that the custom metrics don't show up?
Is the "metrics" section in the azure portal the wrong place to look for custom metrics?

Update

The sample code also doesn't upload any custom metrics to azure.

```
        TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
        client.InstrumentationKey = "a valid key";
        client.GetMetric("test me").TrackValue(200);
        client.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Comment: What is `key` and `val`?

Comment: key = string, val = double, the string has space chars inside

Comment: Ok, I know. I mean what is the value of that variables

Comment: Umm, don't you normally use `TelemetryClient.TrackMetric(string, double)` for custom metrics? Or is this some other way I don't about? :D

Comment: The docs say TelemetryClient.TrackMetric(string, double) is debricated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#trackmetric

Comment: in the applicaion insight ->  search section, can you find the metric? or can you show me the more sample code? For console app, we need add the sleep() and flush() at the end of the code.

Comment: do i need to add the flush? Default performance metrics are uploaded regularly, so i thought i don't need the flush. the app runs now for about 24 hours plus.

Comment: I can't find custom metric key in the search

Comment: ok, so could you please provide an sample code? If the app keeps running, no need to add flush.

Comment: currently not at the workstation, will take until tomorrow to get a sample ready

Comment: it would be helpful if attach screenshot of your metric section on portal.

Comment: @Henk, I cannot figure out what's wrong with it. Even in the Analytics -> CustomMetrics, it's not there. But if use TrackMetric, it's ok.

Comment: So you have the same problem?

Comment: yes, the same issue, not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Henk, issue resolved, you can refer to my answer for details.

Comment: @Henk, if this answer works for you, please help mark it as answer. It would be helpful for others.

Comment: sry had no time to verify, maybe tomorrow. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue due to the instrumentation key is not configured correctly.

When use `GetMetric().TrackValue()`, we should use this way to configure instrumentation key:

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key"`;

My code as below:

```
  TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
  TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key";  
  client.GetMetric("test33").TrackValue(100);  

  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*5);
  client.Flush();

  Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Then in the visual studio output window, you can see the ikey is showing there:
[image]

Then go to azure portal -> application insights -> metrics, you can see your metric:
[image]

For comparison, when you use the following code:

```
client.InstrumentationKey = "a valid key";
client.GetMetric("test me").TrackValue(200);
```

after execution, in the visual studio, you can see there is no ikey in the output window, so no metric would be sent to azure portal:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ivan Yang i found a github issue which is discussing this problem in detail.

It looks like there are multiple cases to create invalid configurations.

For example this is currently also a INVALID configuration

```
TelemetryConfiguration tcConfig = new TelemetryConfiguration();

TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient(tcConfig)
{
    InstrumentationKey = ikey
};
```

More details on https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/826 and on https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/8igabt/using_microsoft_azure_app_insights_and_unity/

Comment: I also submit a issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/936), they will help confirm if it's a bug.